# Pass variable from bash to ruby (Fastlane)

Tags: ruby, bash, fastlane

I have simple bash function like this.

```
jq -e '.expo.isDetached' <app.json
```

I call that sh file in my ruby (Fastlane) like this.

```
check = sh('bash ./Check_Detached.sh')
puts(check)
```

If I print check, it is 'true'.

But if I check 'true' or something, it is never correct.

```
if check == 'true'
```

I think the way how I pass variable from bash function to ruby (Fastlane) is wrong. How shall I do?

Comment: Does `check.size` return `4`? If not then there might be a trailing character that can be chopped. Example `"true\n".chomp`

Comment: Very strange. I write puts(check.size) and it show 123.

Comment: I suspect 'check' contains trailing whitespaces. You could verify with  `check.split(/(.)/)`. And to remove whitespace `check.gsub(/\s/,'')`

Comment: omg it is returning me directory.  /  U  s  e  r  s  /  k  h  a  n  t  t  h  u  l  i  n  n  /  D  o  c  u  m  e  n  t  s  /  R  e  a  c  t  N  a  t  i  v  e  /  N  U  S  T  i  m  e  s  h  e  e  t  /  a  n  d  r  o  i  d 
 /  U  s  e  r  s  /  k  h  a  n  t  t  h  u  l  i  n  n  /  D  o  c  u  m  e  n  t  s  /  R  e  a  c  t  N  a  t  i  v  e  /  N  U  S  T  i  m  e  s  h  e  e  t 
 t  r  u  e 
How shall I check the last 'true' ?

Comment: `check.gsub(/\s/,'')[-4..-1] == true`

Comment: woo..aweseome! it solves now. thanks bro

Comment: Or for better performance `check.delete("\s")[-4..-1]`

Answer (score 1):

You should probably strip your result first: `check = sh('bash ./Check_Detached.sh').strip`.